# How to make an express page that contains all my front-end js scripts?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to make a root where there's all my front end scripts.

So when I want to import my scripts in my `index.html` I just need to do :

```
<script src="/front/scripts"></script>
```

First problem :

This is my server code :

```
app.use('/front/scripts', (req, res) => {
  const readScript = (filePath) => {
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;

      return res.write(data);
    });
  };
  readScript('./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js');
  readScript('./node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js');
  readScript('./src/js/app.js');
});
```

It's not working because express is keep loading the page so I can't import it because my `index.html` is waiting for my `front/scripts` to stop loading.

Second problem:

It will not work because of the size of the file, the lightest file will be loaded faster than a bigger one like jQuery, so the lightest file will be at the top of `front/scripts` and the big one will be after le lightest.

For example if my personal app.js is just a 3 lines jQuery script that change the content of a div, it will return me an error because my script is loaded before jQuery.

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once all scripts have been read and written to `response` finally the `response` must get finalized as well using `res.end();`

Example below has a small change as the `readFile` is `async` so there's no guarantee that `res.end()` is called at the right time. Made it `synced`.

See here [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options).

```
app.use('/front/scripts', (req, res) => {
  const readScript = (filePath) => {
      res.write(fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8'));
  };
  readScript('./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js');
  readScript('./node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js');
  readScript('./src/js/app.js');

  res.end();
});
```

Comment: I've already tried this but it's returning me a blank page. Am i the only one ?
And if i replace the readFileSync for a simple readFile, it will just return my this error : `write after end`

Comment: Have you also tried `readFileSync` instead of `readFile`? Because the blank page indicates the async behavior because `response.end()` is executed before files have been read and therefore the response is empty

Comment: By the way i can do a setTimeout of 1 seconde, but it not seems to be a realy clean way.

Comment: Sorry my mistake put the return of fs.readFileSync directly into the `res.write` then it works on my machine

Comment: Ok with your last edit of the post it seems to work fine ! Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

**Use express.static**

Example:

Sample project setup:

```
server.js
front
  scripts
    app.js
```

server.js:

```js
const express = require('express')
const { join } = require('path')
const app = express()

app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, 'front/scripts'))

app.listen(3000)
```

You'll get your `app.js` here: **localhost:3000/app.js**